# C signal code explanation needed

Tags: c

We came across this snippet of code in our textbook that was lacking explanation
except the fact that it handles signals.

```
#include <signal.h> 
void (*signal(int signr,
            void(*sighandler)(int)
        )
    )(int)
```

I know that `sighandler` is a pointer to a function, but I do not understand if it is actually executed or just returned?

and what does the call with `(int)` do?
It looks almost like a reversed cast.

Comment: [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*signal%28int%2C+void%28*%29%28int%29%29%29%28int%29)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the signature of the `signal` function.

The first argument `signr` is of type `int` and is the signal whose handler you want to change.

The second argument `sighandler` is a function pointer of type `void (*)(int)`, i.e. a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`.  This parameter is the name of a function which will handle the signal.

The function returns a function pointer of type `void (*)(int)` (same type as argument 2) which points to the previous signal handling function.

Breaking it down:

```
 signal                                 // signal
 signal()                               // is a function
 signal(int)                            // taking a int
 signal(int, void (*)(int))             // and a function pointer
                                        // which takes an int and return void
 (*signal)(int, void (*)(int))(int)     // and returns a function pointer
                                        // which takes an int
 void (*signal)(int, void (*)(int))(int)   // and returns void
```

The man page includes a typedef which makes this a bit more clear:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```